# Which tables has information of all page titles and liferay navigation menu titles in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I can rename liferay page titles and titles of liferay navigation menus from the web application(as Liferay admin user) but i want to know which table is updated. I couldn't find them in Liferay schema. What are all tables Liferay use for this ?

Comment: Jorge has mentioned the big disclaimer in his answer. Here's what you need to know about Liferay's database: https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/understanding-liferay-s-database. On top: Voting to close, because this question is not about programming, but about details of a stock software, thus off topic on stackoverflow. See [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one big disclaimer:

- Most of the times, when somebody asks for the tables where information is stored, is because he wants to update it without using Liferay API
- MODIFYING DATABASE DATA IS A VERY BAD IDEA YOU CAN CAUSE A LOT OF ISSUES IN YOUR SYSTEM
- Always update stored data using Liferay API!

About the information you asked, they are stored in several tables and they change depending on which Liferay version you are using.

Some tables where that information is stored in 7.2 are:

- FriendlyUrlEntryLocalization
- Layout
- LayoutBranch
- LayoutFriendlyUrl
- SiteNavigationMenu
- SiteNavigationMenuItem

Answer (score -1):

the table "layout" contains all pages.

Comment: That was already part of the existing, 2 years old, answer. No need to post it again.